# Best practice for creating dependent fields/pick-list

Tags: reporting, formula-field, picklist, dependent-picklist

we have few requests in reporting modules that requires:

two letter country code instead of full name. e.g. United States should display as US. And I need separate field for that

What is the best way of doing this? Pick-list, formula(case)? We have 200+ records.

Comment: Do you know that you have access to country codes for standard fields in Salesforce? For example, if the field concerned is `Account`->`BillingCountry`, you can access the code using: `Account`->`BillingCountryCode`

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer, still trying to figure this out. I know that there is an feature for standard objects, but we are using custom object/field. Time zone I can figure out trough user records, but for Custom object of Team Member which holds Country - I need a way to display 2 letter code for that country... I can write formula using Case but for 250 countries it wont compile...

Comment: This is a standard field, so you can use the picklist and please follow the below link to do so.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_state_country_picklist_enable.htm&type=0